# Item popularity in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
ItemId Items views
1 - item1 - 4
2 - item2 - 3
3 - item3 - 3
```

I would live to know how populair a product is

the result should be

```
item 1: first place
item 2: second place
item 3: second place
```

I have a very hard time figuring out how to do this in mysql. Is there a query that will to exactly this ? Especially when a user is on the item3 page I would like to say: this is the second most popular product

Any help would greatly appreciated !

Comment: `SELECT ItemId, Items, Views FROM product ORDER BY Views DESC`

Comment: Thats is not gonna work, first because, on the item3 page I don't know how popular that item is. I would have to loop the entire query (and it's a lare table) Second it will show up on the third row where it should end op as tied for second place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using correlated subquery.

```
SELECT Items,
       (SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT b.views) 
        FROM    tableName b
        WHERE   a.views <= b.views
       ) as rank
FROM    tableName a
ORDER   BY Views DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e47bc/7)

Comment: added `ORDER BY` clause, [here's another example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8feb6/1)